# Plot summaries for the other two movies related to Moon

Tags: movie-franchise, moon

[Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_%28film%29), the 2009 British science fiction drama film directed by Duncan Jones, is suppose to be the first in a "[trilogy of films set in the same fictional universe.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_%28film%29#Sequels)"

**What are the plot summaries for the other two movies?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second film in the trilogy is supposed to be *Mute*. Duncan Jones has stated it is a Blade Runner inspired movie, which he is a big fan of, and it takes place in a futuristic Berlin.

About the third film, there is not much known but I remember one of his interviews where he has said the third film could be the adaptation of *Escape from the Deep* which is an underwater epic focusing on a submarine and her crew.

Anyway, you can [follow him](https://twitter.com/#!/ManMadeMoon/) on Twitter where he provides info on his future projects as well. In April, he announced another project which is a non sci-fi movie.

[image: image of tweet, click to go to Twitter]

Answer (score 1):

### MUTE (in development)

[image: MUTE-image]
[**CAPTION:** Artist depiction from the homepage [Liberty Films](http://www.liberty-films.co.uk/), the film's production company.]

[As stated in the selected answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/2346/1309), the movie appears to be inspired by Blade Runner.